# Debugging Javascript / Jquery in Visual Studio 2010 MVC3 Razor in a partial View

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging, razor

Is it possible to debug jquery in Visual Studio MVC3 Razor in a partial view?  The breakpoints I set within a regular view are hit, however, when I set breakpoints in a partial view loaded within that view, they aren't.  I know the javascript is working, just wondering if this is a limitation with debugging script in partial views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using "**debugger;**" command in javascript?

Answer (score -1):

You should use your browser to debug javascript. Most modern browsers have a debugger as part of their Developer Tools. E.g., in Internet Explorer, hit F12.

Comment: this is not even close to being an attempt at answering the question as asked.

Comment: @SkySanders How so? This is how you debug javascript.

Comment: @jrummell Not when Visual Studio is attached, because then you can't use IE's script debugger.